# Liaison entre « (tu) as » et un participe passé comme dans « Tu as écouté »

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, liaisons

J'ai entendu un locuteur natif dire :

> Tu as écouté ce qu'il faut faire !

en faisant la liaison entre as et écouté. Je n'ai pas observé cette liaison. Est-elle facultative ? Fautive ?

Comment: Oui, il s'agit d'une liaison facultative – on peut le vérifier [ici](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais). Je crois que je l'ai entendu de temps à autre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est une liaison facultative. Le cas est listé dans [l'article Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_facultative) :

> - entre les formes des auxiliaires *avoir* ou *être* et le participe passé : *ils ont aimé*, *elle est allée*, *nous sommes arrivés* ;

C'est aussi le cas avec des verbes qui prennent un autre verbe comme complément : *tu dois écouter*, *tu peux écouter*, *il faut écouter*, ...

Cela dit, dans ce cas particulier, la liaison est très rare. Curieusement, je trouve que la liaison dans « *tu as‿écouté* » ou « *tu as‿entendu* » sonne mal et je ne la ferais jamais, alors que je ferais la liaison dans « *vous avez‿écouté* » ou « *vous avez‿entendu* » en prononciation soutenue (mais pas dans la vie courante). L'article Wikipédia note cette particularité sans explication, et cite Grevisse p. 49 pour déconseiller la liaison du -s à la deuxième personne du singulier.

J'ai l'impression que c'est plus compliqué que ça mais je ne sais pas quelles sont les règles. Je ne perçois pas de différence sur la propension à faire la liaison entre « j'avais‿écouté » et « tu avais‿écouté » (faible dans les deux cas), et je ne m'entends pas du tout faire la liaison dans « elle avait‿écouté ». Par contre je trouve la liaison dans « elle est‿allée » tout à fait naturelle, alors que je ne la ferais en général pas dans « tu es‿allé(e) ».

Comment: Similar to « vous avez », notice « nous avons eu » in the introduction to [this video from 1958](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCAmRV1snYc) (around [0:25](https://youtu.be/WCAmRV1snYc?t=25)).

Comment: Curieusement je pense faire la liaison dans la majorité des exemples donnés par wikipédia comme facultatifs, mais effectivement avec l'exemple de l'OP je pense ne jamais la faire...